# setOnItemClickListener for cwac-endless list

Tags: android

I'm currently using cwac-endless adapter for my application. For this one, I don't know how to integrate setOnItemClickListener in cwac-endless class.

Here is my/his coding and please help me to answer how to integrate setOnItemClickListner.

```
    DemoAdapter(ArrayList<String> list) {
      super(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Lists.this,
                                      R.layout.row,
                                      android.R.id.text1,
                                      list));

      rotate = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                                  0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                                  0.5f);
      rotate.setDuration(600);
      rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
      rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    }
```

Comment: You want to integrate where in this Adapter class in your activity? What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What I want to get is to put setOnItemClickListner event on this ArrayAdapter.

Comment: But `setOnItemClickListner` is attached with class like `AdapterView`  or derived from this. So you are trying to do something different. Again what exactly you are trying to achieve? Some snippet also will be helpful

Comment: what I'm trying to achieve is want to go next intent and displaying appropriate value in it. Can you show complete coding as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got the answer as adding following coding

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cfword = items.get(position);        
}
```